# kustomize uses wrong api version

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kustomize

When I kustomize the cockroachdb helm chart with `kubectl kustomize`, the wrong kubernetes api version is used for some ressources.

kustomization

```
piVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: apps

generators:
  - cockroachdbChart.yaml
```

Helm Chart Inflator:

```
apiVersion: builtin
kind: HelmChartInflationGenerator
metadata:
  name: crdb
name: cockroachdb
repo: https://charts.cockroachdb.com/
version: 10.0.3
releaseName: crdb
namespace: apps
IncludeCRDs: true
```

When I now run `kubectl kustomize --enable-helm` in the directory with those files, some are rendered with the `v1beta1` version, even if the kubernetes version only supports version `v1`:

```
» kubectl kustomize --enable-helm crdb-test | grep -A 5 -B 1 v1beta
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: crdb
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
--
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: crdb
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
--
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: crdb
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
```

These are the kubectl and helm versions I have installed:

```
» kubectl version --short 
Client Version: v1.24.3
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.25.4
» helm version --short
v3.10.3+gd506314
```

Is this a kustomize error?
Can I set the api Version that kustomize uses in the kustomization file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kustomize doesn't know anything about what API versions are supported by your target environment, nor does it change the API versions in your source manifests.

If you're getting output with inappropriate API versions, the problem is not with Kustomize but with the source manifests.

We see the same behavior if we remove Kustomize from the equation:

```
$ helm template cockroachdb/cockroachdb | grep -B1 CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
--
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
```

The problem here is the logic in the Helm chart, which looks [like this](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/cronjob-ca-certSelfSigner.yaml):

```
{{- if and .Values.tls.enabled (and .Values.tls.certs.selfSigner.enabled (not .Values.tls.certs.selfSigner.caProvided)) }}
  {{- if .Values.tls.certs.selfSigner.rotateCerts }}
    {{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "batch/v1/CronJob" }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
    {{- else }}
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
    {{- end }}
```

That relies on the value of `.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "batch/v1/CronJob"`, which requires Helm to query the remote Kubernetes environment to check if the server supports that API version. That doesn't happen when using `helm template` (or Kustomize, which is really just wrapping `helm template` when exploding helm charts).

The correct fix would be for the CockroachDB folks to update the helm charts to introduce a variable that controls this logic explicitly.

You can patch this in your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

generators:
  - cockroachdbChart.yaml

patches:
  - target:
      kind: CronJob
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /apiVersion
        value: batch/v1
```

Which results in:

```
$ kustomize build --enable-helm | grep -B1 CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
--
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
```